# Sound Design/Sound Engineering Masters in Europe

Tags: audio, design, education, master, university

I studied Computer Engineering in Italy and now I'm searching for a Master in sound in Europe.
I want to explore mainly the technical aspects of the Sound Engineering, like recordig and post-production,also for films.

Can you recommend some school?

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't work on this type of question, where every answer is simply someone's opinion & no one of those can be 'correct'. Please see the help pages, especially https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Well, it USED to…back when the forum was called Social Sound Design before Stack Exchange absorbed it. It's a shame that people can't come here with this type of open-ended question anymore without being flagged down or down voted. There are SO many contributors here that are qualified, willing and able to answer this posters question, thereby enabling @Haskell to find the resources he needs

Comment: @JayJennings - I'm very surprised by your comment. I don't know of any SE site that would welcome this type of question, It's a 'shopping request' or at best a list question in any other form; off-topic, grid-wide. Opinion-based & nothing more.

Comment: Don't be too surprised…as one of the last holdouts from the original Social Sound Design forum I've been very vocal about this sort of thing in the past. Like I said, this type of question USED to be welcome, and indeed encouraged, as the original forum was created to be a place where people could exchange ideas, ask open questions, and form their own answers. SE isn't like that at all, and that's the rub. My comment is not meant to offend; rather, it's meant to encourage new contributors to continue asking so that the community can help them. Some questions will never have an 'answer'.

Comment: @Tetsujin - this site came from a very different background. It was a forum, and discussion was encouraged. I think some parts of the merge with SE worked, but others really didn't, so that collaborative, informal element went, along with a number of smart sound folks.

Comment: @JayJennings & Rory, I don't know the full history - I joined after the 'great fall out' that went on & though I read back as much as I could about it, really once all the old stalwarts left for good, what was left is what we have now... a beta stack barely scraping by on enough relevant posts to keep it alive. My initial comment, however, was pretty much the same as I would have added to a similar question on any stack, it wasn't specific to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Iain McGregor's course at Edinburgh Napier University, UK? Although he is listed as a lecturer conducting research into sound design and listening, there may be other courses offered alongside that fit your needs:

https://www.napier.ac.uk/people/iain-mcgregor

Here in the USA, I can recommend the Music Production and Engineering program at Berklee College Of Music, Boston MA:

https://www.berklee.edu/mpe/bachelor-of-music-in-music-production-and-engineering

And the Audio Production program at Full Sail University, Orlando, Florida:

https://www.fullsail.edu/degrees/audio-production-bachelor

Best of luck, @Haskell!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options in France :

https://www.ens-louis-lumiere.fr/specialite-son

http://www.femis.fr/departement-son

http://www.conservatoiredeparis.fr/disciplines/les-disciplines/les-disciplines-detail/discipline/formation-superieure-aux-metiers-du-son/